# Big O confusion

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, landau-notation

I have a question asking about a language L with the property: there is a TM that decides L in time O(n^2013 / (log(n))^2012), and if there is a TM that decides L in time O(n^2012.9).

My confusion comes from the first big O given, from what I understand the numerator would dominate as the TM grows towards infinity, so it would end up being O(n^2013), which would grow faster then O(n^2012.9), so there could not be a TM that decides L in time O)n^2012.9). But I'm not sure how to go about proving this. Is there some theorem that let's you compare O(n^2/log(n)) with O(n) or something to that extent?

Comment: First a hint, what you fundamentally want to show is that $\log n \in O(n^{c})$ for any $c > 0$ (particularly including $c < 1$ as well), you can then extrapolate this to $n^{c}/(\log n)^{d}$ is always eventually greater than $1$, hence $n^{c} \in O(n^{c+\varepsilon}/(\log n)^{d})$. Second, it's not clear to me what you're actually trying to prove, I don't see why having a TM with a particular running time necessarily prohibits a more efficient one from existing. Plus your first paragraph is grammatically wobbly, and thus confusing "... and if...", then what?